# Exception while installing Sonarqube6.1 on Linux

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

While installing `Sonarqube6.1` on Linux 64 bit, I'm getting this error in the log file:

```
2016.12.01 20:18:56 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/sonar]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.server.platform.ws.SystemWs

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.server.platform.ws.InfoAction

        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.server.platform.monitoring.SonarQubeMonitor
```

Comment: Are you trying to listen on a privilege port as a non-privileged user?

Comment: Can you provide the complete sonar.log on pastebin (for instance) ?

Comment: please provide a more extensive extract from sonar.log (if not all of it). You might have missed something. Also, indicate the JDK SQ is running with and describe how you installed SQ. Finally, as for any StackOverflow question, describe what you tried to fix the error and how it went.

Comment: Did you unzip in a fresh directory but not over an existing installation ?

Comment: I am not able to add in "Add Comment" Section as it does not allow for more characters after certain limitation. Please share me some emails so that i can send those on their email.

Comment: @AmishGupta You can edit the original question.

Comment: @Jeroen-Trying to copy that but i am getting error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."  Please share email id

Comment: @JeroenHeier ??

Comment: @G. Ann - Can you please help me here?